# Hashtags on Newsfeed webpart not clickable

Tags: newsfeed, hashtags

So I was tasked with setting up a newsfeed for a page for my team. I turned on the site feed under the site settings. Another requirement was hashtags. I added hashtags to some test posts by selecting them from ones that were suggested. It adds them, but they are not clickable. The same is for other pages across our other sites.

Am I missing another setting, or setup? Did MSOFT deprecate hashtags working in newsfeeds to push users to use Yammer?